# SparkR for streaming with spark 1.6

Tags: spark-streaming, sparkr

Any idea whether sparkR for spark 1.6 is capable of calling methods for streaming e.g. say streaming liner regression with SGD. If yes, can anyone please share any references. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now SparkR doesn't support streaming and it is rather unlikely it will in the nearest future. For starters it would require a lower level R API which is still in a design phase. Morover R is probably not best choice for a real time processing.

Comment: Any suggestions what would be a better alternative for streaming in R? Does RStorm serve the purpose?